# gradle options don't include changing java version

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to run a flutter project and I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I checked all solutions and they all about changing the java version in gradle setting but when I open it, it doesn't include that option. Is there any alternative solution?[the gradle options photo is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od5Qs.png)

Answer (score 0):

the same problem.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s